# increment two variables in a loop one line python3 syntax error

Tags: python-3.x

why am I receiving an error when I try to increase the variables in a single line?

```
one = 12
two = 13

while one + two <40:
    one,two = one+=1, two+=1
```

Comment: And the error message says...?

Comment: Because you are using three assignments on the same line.

Comment: You cannot have more than one operator in line (you got 3: `=`, `+=`, `+=`). Go with `one, two = one + 1, two + 1` and that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to change the values like that

```
one = one+=1
```

And this is invalid because `one+=1` is actually increasing your `one` value already

You can achieve what you trying to do in those ways

**First way**

```
one, two = 12, 13

while one + two < 40:
    one+=1
    two+=1
```

**Second way**

```
one, two = 12, 13

while one + two < 40:
    one, two = one + 1, two +1
```